# using a for loop to create tr's and td's in a table element \\ unable to parse results from td's

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, createelement

I am creating a table that creates tr's and td's within a table. The table with loop through a subtraction calculation and create a column of the results from the for loop. When I try to add the next column it does not parse the calculations but continues to perform calculations

```
for (i=foo; i<bar+1; i++)
{               
    var tableNode = document.getElementById('tableID');

    var trNode = document.createElement('tr');
    var trValue = '';

    var tdNode = document.createElement('td');
    var tdValue = parseFloat(i) + parseFloat(500); //this is calculating 500 and not concatenating 500 for every iteration.

    trNode.innerHTML = trValue;
    tdNode.innerHTML = tdValue;

    tableNode.appendChild(trNode);
    trNode.appendChild(tdNode);             
}
```

The goal is to do using a for loop that populates the tr's and td's

1 500

2 500

3 500

Comment: Use parseInt and not parseFloat

Comment: Try adding an empty string in-between. var tdValue = parseFloat(i) + "" + parseFloat(500);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `<table>` & `for` loops

If you want to generate a `<table>` with a `for` loop you should use two `for` loops -- first loop is for rows and the second loop is for cells for each row. The following demo has the following:

- A `<form>` that has:

  - An `<input>` to enter the number of rows.
  - An `<input>` to enter the number of cells per row.
  - button to trigger the click event that calls the function `generateTable()`.
- The `<form>` and all of its form controls are accessed by using **[HTMLFormControlsCollection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)**.
- The methods **[`.insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)** and **[`.insertCell()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)** will automatically create an element and append it.

The `<form>` and all that's related to it are optional of course, it's just added for demonstration purposes. The loops can be used alone by just assigning numbers to variables `rowQty` and `celQty`.

### Demo

```js
/*
Optional
*/
var ui = document.forms[0].elements;
var btn = ui.btn;

btn.onclick = generateTable;

/*
Required
*/
function generateTable(e) {
  var table = document.getElementById('T0');
  /*
  if used without the <form>
  replace the next two lines with:
  */
  //var rowQty = {any integer}
  //var celQty = {any integer 2 or greter}
  var rowQty = ui.rowData.value;
  var celQty = ui.celData.value;

  for (let i = 0; i < rowQty; i++) {
    var tr = table.insertRow(i);
    for (let j = 0; j < celQty; j++) {
      var td = tr.insertCell(j);
      if (j === 0) {
        td.textContent = i + 1;
      } else if (j === 1) {
        td.textContent = "500";
      } else {
        td.textContent = " ";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: right;
}

td {
  min-width: 3ch;
  max-width: 150px;
}

td:first-of-type {
  width: 3ch;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 5ch;
}
```

```html
<!-- Optional -->
<form id='ui'>
  <label for='rowData'>Rows: </label>
  <input id='rowData' type='number' min='1' max='10' value='1'>
  <label for='celData'>Cells per Row: </label>
  <input id='celData' type='number' min='2' max='10' value='2'>
  <button id='btn' type='button'>GO</button>
</form>

<!-- Required -->
<table id='T0'></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```js
let foo = 1,
  bar = 3;

for (let i = foo; i <= bar; i++) {
  var tableNode = document.getElementById("tableID");

  let trNode = document.createElement("tr");
  let trValue = "";

  let tdNode = document.createElement("td");
  let tdValue = parseFloat(i) + ' ' + parseFloat(500);

  trNode.innerHTML = trValue;
  tdNode.innerHTML = tdValue;

  trNode.appendChild(tdNode);
  tableNode.appendChild(trNode);
}
```

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableID"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate `parseFloat(i)` and `parseFloat(500)`, do:

```
var tdValue = parseFloat(i) + " " + parseFloat(500);
```

instead of `parseFloat(i) + parseFloat(500)` because this will add the float values and `tdValue` will be the sum (of type **number**).

Note the `" "` (string containing a space) in the middle which will consider the elements to be concatenated as **strings** and the result of the concatenation to be of type **string**.